# Instance object getting deleted when tried to print it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to overload `new` and this is my attempt:-

```
class String(object):
  def __new__(cls, *args, **kargs):
    print "in __new__"
    return super(String, cls).__new__(cls)
  def __init__(self):
    print "Initiating instance of String"
    raise Exception
  def __del__(self):
    print "Deleting instance of String"
```

I read at many places that actually `__new__` create the instance and `__init__` is just to initialize the instance. I am deliberately throwing exception in `__init__` to let it fail. Here call to `new` returns the instance but `init` fails, so I am expecting an instance which won't have any attributes. But result surprised me like anything -

```
st = String()
in __new__
Initiating instance of String

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#89>", line 1, in <module>
    st = String()
  File "<pyshell#88>", line 7, in __init__
    raise Exception
```

As expected it failed in `__init__`, Next I tried to print newly created instance `'st'` and result surprised me, it deleted instance before printing.

```
>>> print st
**Deleting instance of String**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#90>", line 1, in <module>
    print st
NameError: name 'st' is not defined
```

Please help me to understand this strange behavior.

Note - I know when we should overload `__new__` and when we shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exception was raised before Python managed to assign the object in memory to the the variable name. Therefore the *reference counter* of the object in memory is *0*, so it got 'garbage collected', and you got `name is not defined` exception.

**Update for the comment**:
Python runs GC when it tries to allocate memory for a new object, if the threshold is filled. In your case it's probably the threshold for generation 0 that was reached, because it's where that new 'failed' `String` object should have been. And the event itself that triggered GC was memory allocation to execute `print`.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I am trying to find why it got 'garbage collected' when I tried to print it.